# How can I fix ninja: error: loading 'build.ninja': The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: vscode-extensions, esp-idf, espressif-idf

I installed esp-idf extension(version 1.6.4) using VsCode then I configured it by choosing Express option then I selected v5.1 (release version) after that I clicked  on install.
I created a project using hello_world template but when I click on build I get this error on the terminal.

> ninja: error: loading 'build.ninja': The system cannot find the file specified
> The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command ninja " terminated with exit code: 1.

I tried to setup the environment again but I got the same error